# VSCode SSH keeps timing out

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I'm trying to connect to a Linux server via VSCode and am having some trouble doing so due to timeout errors. The output from the terminal looks like this:

```
[06:48:24.979] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+name", attempt 2, (Reconnection)
[06:48:24.985] SSH Resolver called for host: name
[06:48:24.986] Setting up SSH remote "name"
[06:48:24.987] Using commit id "6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b" and quality "stable" for server
[06:48:24.995] Install and start server if needed
```

My config file looks like this:

```
Host name
    HostName 192.123.145.32
    User user
    Port 51600
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa

Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The steps that I've taken are:

1. Change the default timing out from 15 seconds to 60.
2. Set the "Use Local Server" flag in the Remote-SSH settings to False.

Neither seem to be working and I'm not sure what else I can try.

Comment: I get this problem intermittently too, despite direct SSH from <insert any SSH client here> working perfectly fine. Currently the only workaround is to hard-wipe the ".vscode-server" folder from the remote user's home directory, but the problem comes back soon.